# What kind of test/bench will show performance gain from using copy_file_range() syscall?

Tags: linux-kernel, benchmarking, system-calls, btrfs

I have two kernels: default 4.4.26 and 4.4.26 with [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7592331/). What kind of test or benchmark should I run on my btrfs partition to see performance gain from applying the 
above-stated patch?

Comment: Presumably something like `cp -a src_dir new_dir_tree`, and then the same thing with a version of `cp` that uses copy_file_range instead of reading the source files itself.

Comment: It's a brand new syscall, so it doesn't speed up any existing code.  You need user-space software that takes advantage of it.  IDK if that's what you're asking.